# Android Webview: navigator.geolocation API is not working, throwing exception POSITION_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: android, android-studio, geolocation, android-webview

I'm trying to embed a web appliation into Android Webview. My web application using HTML5 Geolocation API to get the current location of the user. Now we are trying to create an android app which opens it in the webview and user is able to perform the same action from the mobile app as well. 
In Webview we are not able to see any kind of message where user ask to allow or denied as we see in browser and it throws error of `POSITION_UNAVAILABLE`.

#### Web Application JS code related to geolocation API

```
// Geolocation fetch function for getting value 
function fetchGeoLocationFunction(result){
    if(result ==  true){
        // reset the search location to initiate with the new process
        resetAddressSelection();
        if (navigator.geolocation){            
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
        }
        else {
            var msgToDisplay = 'Geolocation is not supported by your browser or device, Please try with any latest popular browser';
            CreatePopupMessage(false,msgToDisplay,'Not Supported',false);            
        }
    }
}

function showPosition(position){   
    var attempt = 1;
    convertGeoCordstoAddress(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude,attempt);
}

function showError(error){
showProcessingBar(); // Show the Processing Bar
setTimeout(function(){
   hideProcessingBar();
   console.log('Its in failure',error.code);
   var err_Msg = '';
   switch(error.code){    
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          err_Msg = 'You have denied the Request for your Geo location, without that You can\'t proceed further. Please allow this operation from your browser settings'
          break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          err_Msg ='Location information is unavailable. please try after some time'
          break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
          err_Msg ='The request to get user location timed out.Please try again'
          break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          err_Msg ='An unknown error occurred. if the error is repetative, please contact to application provider'
          break;
   }   
   if(err_Msg == ''){
       err_Msg  = 'An Error Occured, Contact to Application provider';
   }
   //alert(err_Msg);
   CreatePopupMessage(false,err_Msg,'',true);   
},500);  
}
```

Here is my android app code starts

### Android app code

#### MainActivuty.java

```
package com.example.timedin;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout;

import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;
    private int webViewPreviousState;
    private final int PAGE_STARTED = 0x1;
    private final int PAGE_REDIRECTED = 0x2;
    private CoordinatorLayout rootView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // webview initilization
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);

        /// Below required for geolocation
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());
        webView.loadUrl("<my_webapp_url>");

    }

    /**
     * WebChromeClient subclass handles UI-related calls
     * Note: think chrome as in decoration, not the Chrome browser
     */
    public class GeoWebChromeClient extends android.webkit.WebChromeClient {
        @Override
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin,
                                                       final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {

            // permission and the user has therefore already granted it
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);

        }
    }

    /**
     * WebViewClient subclass loads all hyperlinks in the existing WebView
     */
    public class GeoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // When user clicks a hyperlink, load in the existing WebView
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        Dialog loadingDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            webViewPreviousState = PAGE_STARTED;
            //CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
            if (loadingDialog == null || !loadingDialog.isShowing())
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                        "Loading Please Wait", true, true,
                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                // do something
                            }
                        });

            loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
                                    WebResourceError error) {


            if (isConnected()) {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "onReceivedError : " + error.getDescription(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackBar.setAction("Reload", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            } else {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "No Internet Connection ", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackBar.setAction("Enable Data", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                        snackBar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            }

            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view,
                                        WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {

            if (isConnected()) {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "HttpError : " + errorResponse.getReasonPhrase(), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

                snackBar.setAction("Reload", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            } else {
                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(rootView, "No Internet Connection ", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                snackBar.setAction("Enable Data", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS), 0);
                        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload( true )");
                        snackBar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();
            }
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (webViewPreviousState == PAGE_STARTED) {

                if (null != loadingDialog) {
                    loadingDialog.dismiss();
                    loadingDialog = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Check if there is any connectivity
     *
     * @return is Device Connected
     */
    public boolean isConnected() {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (null != cm) {
            NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return (info != null && info.isConnected());
        }

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                // Initial
                perms.put(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);


                // Fill with results
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);

                // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                if (perms.get(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED


                ) {
                    // All Permissions Granted

                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All Permission GRANTED !! Thank You :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "One or More Permissions are DENIED Exiting App :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                    finish();
                }
            }
            break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void fuckMarshMallow() {
        List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

        final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (!addPermission(permissionsList, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
            permissionsNeeded.add("Show Location");

        if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
            if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {

                // Need Rationale
                String message = "App need access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);

                for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                    message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);

                showMessageOKCancel(message,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                            }
                        });
                return;
            }
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No new Permission Required- Launching App .You are Awesome!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }


    private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {

        if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            // Check for Rationale Option
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

So everytime when I run the app in android Webview, it didn't ask anything it just show me popup message with error, `POSITION_UNAVAILABLE` error from the JS code, which gives error `Location information is unavailable. please try after some time`

I've tried other code logic and read various other answers but none of them worked. I'm currently Testing with `android pie` version, but tried other versions as well, it is not working.

Comment: What is wrong with the question, is it not properly explained? really disappointed not getting any help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's check the permission code the issue is in calling of it. and I don't know why you're calling permission in this way as, we've lot of mediums by which you can easily call it. Let's use [nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions) it's easy to use.

Call in this way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                .....................


String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
Permissions.check(this/*context*/, permissions, null/*rationale*/, null/*options*/, new 
PermissionHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onGranted() {
    // call your task

    // webview initilization
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);

    /// Below required for geolocation
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());
    webView.loadUrl("<my_webapp_url>");


  }

  @Override
  public void onDenied(Context context, ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
      // permission denied, block the feature.
    Toast.makeText(this,"Permission denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  }

});
```

Or implement these permission overrides function on basis of your need.

Comment: Thanks,I tried your way but it is not showing any kind of alert at all. I can't see the exception but at the same time I can't get the coordinates as well.

Comment: can you please tell me the device name on which it's not working. As, the coordinates takes a minute or two in fetching.

Comment: It worked later on, I believe it was problem from the device itself, I was trying on android simulator, when I tried with my phone itself it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not requesting the runtime permission. Use something like this:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Permission is not granted
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
    } else {
        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
} else {
    // Permission has already been granted
}
```

Check https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes.html for details.

Comment: Diego first of all Thanks for helping out here, I'm new in Android dev Can you please guide me where should I add this line of code. For your reference I updated the MainActivity.java class because I did some run-time permission check in my code, but not sure why it is not working

Comment: This is a guide for requesting app permissions: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html